# couchdb empty over local network

Tags: couchdb

I've set up CouchDB on a local server. It works fine on the local server.
I've opened the server on the local network by setting bind_address = 0.0.0.0 in local.ini.

When I make a db query from a remote machine on local area I get a result with 0 doc while I get several docs on the local machine.

```
$>> curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbnew

{"db_name":"dbnew","doc_count":125,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":125,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":114799,"data_size":56634,"instance_start_time":"1511017391973208","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":125}

$>> curl -X GET http://192.168.0.8:5984/dbnew

{"db_name":"dbnew","doc_count":0,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":0,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":114799,"data_size":0,"instance_start_time":"1511017142932001","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":0}
```

Any idea why CouchDB returns empty an db from remote machine ?

Comment: You appear to be talking to different databases.  The difference between "instance_start_time" values is a strong clue.

Comment: Hi Flimzy, thx for you reply, how can i check what is the db used ?

Comment: What I mean is you appear to be connecting to different servers. Your IP addresses apparently don't map to the same physical machine.

Comment: great, you're right, i'have two instance of couchdb running at the same time. Thanks.